# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2,3' to data type int Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the stored procedure, an error occurs. Please suggest how to fix this error.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllEmployees]    
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ISNULL(e.Id, '') AS [Id], 
        ISNULL(e.FirstName, '') AS [First Name],
        ISNULL(e.LastName, '') AS [LastName],
        ISNULL(e.Gender, '') AS [Gender], 
        ISNULL(e.DOB, '') AS [DOB],
        ISNULL(c.Hobby, '') AS [Hobby],
        ISNULL(e.Photo, '') AS [Photo],
        ISNULL(e.City, '') AS [City]
    FROM 
        Login e
    INNER JOIN
        tblHobby c ON e.Hobby = c.Id
END
```

My First table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Login] (
    [Id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] VARCHAR (30)   NULL,
    [LastName]  VARCHAR (30)   NULL,
    [Gender]    VARCHAR (6)    NULL,
    [DOB]       DATETIME       NULL,
    [Hobby]     NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Photo]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [City]      VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Login] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Secound Table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblHobby] (
    [Id]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Hobby] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblHobby] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What is the error?  I also changed the tag to SQL Server, because this looks like SQL Server code.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2,3' to data type int ...@GordonLinoff

Comment: `login.hobby` isn't a comma separated list of hobby IDs, is it? If it is, check this: ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad?r=SearchResults&s=1|189.8108) And then change your schema.

Comment: Please **show us** the table structure (the `CREATE TABLE` statements) for both these tables, and show us some **sample data** that you have in those tables

Comment: @Nikunj . . . Your `JOIN` condition (`e.Hobby = c.Id`) is highly suspicious, but you have not provided enough information in the question to help anyone answer.

Comment: sir ,i Edit my question @GordonLinoff

Comment: Seems like you're trying to compare the  Hobby varchar value `'2,3'` with an integer.

Comment: @Nikunj I have made the query. Reopen this question so that i can post my answer.

Comment: How Can reopen ???@Atk

Comment: Ask a new question

Comment: First split string see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: sir,plz post answer in this question @Atk

Comment: @Atk no, don't repost questions, that will simply get the new question locked.

Comment: Users cannot post answers to closed questions, @Nikunj . You need to improve your question sufficiently so that it can then cycle through reopen queue successfully.

Comment: @Atk , if delet This Question , then I Cant Able to Post New Question

Comment: @Nikunj i cant post my answer here. I am not getting option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ISNULL` is the opposite to `COALESCE`, it will always return the type of first argument, so you should do conversions to `VARCHAR`. The error is because your `JOIN` clause `tblHobby c ON e.Hobby = c.Id` implicitlly tries to convert `e.Hobby` to an `int` to compare. As you have a delimited value in that column, the database fails to convert the value.

Try this:

```
tblHobby c ON ',' + ISNULL(e.Hobby, '') + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(c.Id AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ',%'
```

Comment: it's Give All selected value in new raw , but i want I value in One Raw

Comment: Than you should specify which value do you want to see.

Comment: sir, I want value Of 'Hobby' Field of table 'tblHobby' in Single Raw...........tblHobby c ON ',' + ISNULL(e.Hobby, '') + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(c.Id AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ',%'       In this I get value In saparate Raw

Comment: *"ISNULL in oposite to COALESCE have always type of first argument"* this *implies* that `COALESCE` will return the data type of the last arguement; that isn't true. `COALESCE` is a shorthand `CASE` expression, and `CASE` uses data type precedence. `COALESCE(1,'0')` and `ISNULL(1,'0')` would both return a `int`, not a `varchar` and an `int` respectively.

Comment: [Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence. If all expressions are nonnullable, the result is typed as nonnullable.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types)

Comment: More specific difference on second point: [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#comparing-coalesce-and-isnull): "Data type determination of the resulting expression is different. ISNULL uses the data type of the first parameter, COALESCE follows the CASE expression rules and returns the data type of value with the highest precedence."